# When I click on any edit, it makes all the contacts editable in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angularjs. I am using ng-repeat and displaying information in a table format. When I click on any edit, it makes all the contacts editable in angularjs. I just to edit whichever I click end on.

```js
(function () {
            var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
            

            myApp.factory('myFactory', function () {     
                var factory = {};
                factory.contacts = [{ "id": "1", "firstName": "Amy", "lastName": "Jones", "title": "Sales Representative", "Address1": "90 Street", "City": "Toronto", "State": "Ontario" }, { "id": "2", "firstName": "James", "lastName": "King", "title": "President and CEO", "Address1": "90 Street", "City": "Toronto", "State": "Ontario" }, { "id": "3", "firstName": "Ray", "lastName": "Moore", "title": "VPofSales", "Address1": "2323 Dundas St.", "City": "Mississauga", "State": "Ontario" }, { "id": "4", "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Williams", "title": "VPofEngineering", "Address1": "1343 Steels Ave.", "City": "Brampton", "State": "Ontario" }, { "id": "5", "firstName": "Joe", "lastName": "Doe", "title": "SalesRepresentative", "Address1": "3023 Parkerhill Rd.", "City": "Mississauga", "State": "Ontario" }];
                return factory;
            });

            myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, myFactory) {
                $scope.contacts = myFactory.contacts;

                $scope.contact = {};

                $scope.editContact = function (index) {
                    $scope.editId = index;
                    $scope.contact = $scope.contacts[index];
                    console.log($scope.contact);
                }

                $scope.deleteContact = function (index) {
                    $scope.contacts.splice(index, 1);
                }
                
            });
        })();
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-12">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>First Name</td>
                    <td>Last Name</td>
                    <td>Title</td>
                    <td>Address1</td>
                    <td>City</td>
                    <td>State</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="currentContact in contacts">
                    <td class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2 col-xs-1">
                        {{currentContact.id}} 
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2 col-xs-1">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="currentContact.firstName" ng-show="editId != undefined">
                        <span ng-hide="editId != undefined">{{ currentContact.firstName }}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2 col-xs-1">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="currentContact.lastName" ng-show="editId != undefined">
                        <span ng-hide="editId != undefined">{{ currentContact.lastName }}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-xs-2">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="currentContact.title" ng-show="editId != undefined">
                        <span ng-hide="editId != undefined">{{ currentContact.title }}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-xs-2">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="currentContact.Address1" ng-show="editId != undefined">
                        <span ng-hide="editId != undefined">{{ currentContact.Address1 }}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2 col-xs-1">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="currentContact.City" ng-show="editId != undefined">
                        <span ng-hide="editId != undefined">{{ currentContact.City }}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2 col-xs-1">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="currentContact.State" ng-show="editId != undefined">
                        <span ng-hide="editId != undefined">{{ currentContact.State }}</span>
                    </td>

                    <td class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-xs-3">
                        <span ng-click="editContact($index)" ng-hide="editId != undefined">Edit</span>
                        <span ng-click="save($index)" ng-show="editId != undefined">Save</span>
                        <span ng-click="deleteContact($index)"> | Delete</span>
                    </td>
                   
                </tr>
            </table>           
            <button type="button" data-ng-click="goToHome();" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>  

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It happens because you have the same condition to show/hide on all your elements inside the ng-repeat. Try to change the condition to: editId == $index